# How to add a Button on a slideshow that on click get me to the specific slides on the slideshow

Tags: notebooks, cells, button, slideshows

How can I add buttons on a slide that on click takes me to specific slides on the slideshow?

Answer (score 3):

### Create the [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html)

```
Button["Go there", NotebookLocate["section3"]]
```

### Define the target

Right click the target cell and define a unique cell tag that corresponds to the tag used in [`NotebookLocate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookLocate.html)

[image]